# Another Lisp function refinement

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I've completed the Graham's exercise Chapter 5.8,and my code is:

```
(defun max-min (vec &key (start 0) (end (length vec)))
  (cond 
    ((eql start (1- end)) (values (elt vec start) (elt vec (1- end))))
    ((zerop end) (values nil nil))
    (t 
       (multiple-value-bind (x y) (max-min vec :start (1+ start) :end end)
       (let* ((maxx x)(minn y))
         (values (max maxx (elt vec start)) (min minn (elt vec start))))))))
```

You don't need to worry about the details, basically it just returns the max and min of a given vector in a "value" form.
I use the above recursion to solve the problem, but my teachers marked my function as "almost done" with such critique:

"If a function takes start and end, then length is neither needed nor correct. Length could be > 0 but it's whether start < end or not that matters. Testing end all by itself is not relevant at all."

I am not very clear at this point, I tried getting rid of the (length vec) default value for "end", but then the default value for end becomes nil.
We have clear instrution that "length" should at most be called once.
Could you please give me some hint on this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried calling your function with start = 5 and end = 2?

Comment: why are you using the LET* ? For what?

Comment: yes,I have.I think that would work.

Comment: What happens for (>= start end) ?

Comment: Oops,that is a really good catch,Rainer.
I am simply following the recursion format that the instructor gives us,that for recursion,using let to initialize a local variable.
Now I came to realize I already have them in x and y,really no need to let* them into two extra maxx and minn!

Comment: the (zerop end)  clause makes no sense as such, change it.

Comment: The reason why I have it there is because the teacher has a test case:
(assert-equal (values nil nil) (max-min #())
so I have to state this condition explictly.

Comment: why test for (zerop end) ? test for  (>= start end) and move the clause to the top

Comment: ((>= start end) (values (elt vec start) (elt vec end))))?

I dont think it will work.

Comment: You returning the wrong values.

Comment: no idea here,Rainer,(elt vec int) will not work for "#()".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your lambda list is OK.  The problem is the base case:  `(zerop end)` should be modified so that you also get a sensible result if called like `(min-max myvec :start 5 :end 3)`.

The next critique is about these two lines:

```
   (multiple-value-bind (x y) (max-min vec :start (1+ start) :end end)
   (let* ((maxx x) (minn y))
     ;; ...
```

If you want the results of the recursive call to be named `maxx` and `minn`, why don't you name them like that directly?

```
   (multiple-value-bind (maxx minn) (max-min vec :start (1+ start) :end end)
     ;; ...
```

By the way, you can call them `max` and `min` (there are separate namespaces for variables and functions), or `max-of-rest` and `min-of-rest` (to be more descriptive).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know some of the lisp features you're using, but it looks to me very much like your teacher is incorrect.

> "If a function takes start and end, then length is neither needed nor correct. Length could be 0 but it's whether start < end or not that matters. Testing end all by itself is not relevant at all."

It looks to me like `length` is the default value for `end`, and that you *are* only testing `end`, not testing `length` at all...  His complaint already appears to be addressed.

That said, there are a other things to complain about in that code.  For example, what happens if you call max-min with `end` < `start`?  It looks to me like you'll recurse by incrementing start, until you run out of vector, then you'll get some kind of exception.

Comment: Thanks Adian,you've been most helpful.
I struggle to understand him as well,really have no idea about what he really means.

Comment: Actually,if a excercise is marked"almost done" by this teacher,that means only a very minor change needs to be made.So I am just now working on that part.
btw,do you mean the default value for "end" is length of the vector?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry, misspoke.  But I can't say for sure, I've never used &key arguments.  That's definitely what it looks like to me, though.